# Spectrum On Soap Bubbles

Tags: visible-light

I was taking shower , and I noticed that in a soap bubble I could see different colors of the spectrum combine and move.i know it's not the best way to describe it but yeah.how is it possible? How do different colors move around the bubble?

Comment: This question shows insufficient prior research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_interference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colored fringe effect you see occurs when light travels through a very, very thin layer of transmissive material (oil, water, etc.) and is called an 
"interference pattern". A bubble of soapy water is a perfect example. Now as time goes by, the thickness of the wall of the soap bubble changes as the water evaporates and as air currents blow over the bubble's surface. Since the colors you see depend very sensitively on the thickness of the bubble wall, you will then observe the positions of the colors shifting around as the bubble wall thickness shifts around.

There will then come a point when you see the colored fringes fade away. This happens when the bubble wall gets too thin (because of evaporation) to create those fringes. Shortly after that, the wall gives way and the bubble pops.

Comment: Wow.thats really fascinating. Thanks for helping me understand it.